# Python cross-file search with regexp

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

I have 2 files, and I want to get all lines from file2(fsearch) that contain any given line from file1(forig)
I wrote a simple python script that looks like this:

```
def search_string(w, file):
        global matches
        reg = re.compile((r'(^|^.*\|)' + w.strip("\r\n") + r'(\t|\|).*$'), re.M)
        match = reg.findall(file)
        matches.extend(match)

fsearch_text = fsearch.read()
for fword in forig:
        search_string(fword, fsearch_text)
```

There are about 100,000 lines in file1, and about 200,000 lines in file2, so my script takes about 6 hours to complete.
Is there a better algorithm to achieve the same goal in less time?

Edit:
I should have provided example for why I need regexp:
I am searching a list of words in file1 and trying to match them to translations from file2. If I do not use regexp to limit possible matches, I also match translations for words that only contain the word I search as part of itself, example:
Word I search: 浸し
Matched word: お浸し|御浸し|御したし  &n  boiled greens in bonito-flavoured soy sauce (vegetable side dish)
So I have to limit start of match by either ^ or |, and end of match by \t or |, but capture the whole line

Comment: the use of regular expression and the "compare every line with every line" makes it so slow... 100000*200000=2e10 comparisons with regex

Comment: following your edit, is that possible to index each word ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have both files in memory. You can read them and sort them.

After that, you can compare linearly the lines.

```
f1 = open('e:\\temp\\file1.txt')

lines1 = sorted([line for line in f1])

f2 = open('e:\\temp\\file2.txt')

lines2 = sorted([line for line in f2])

i1 = 0
i2 = 0
matchCount = 0
while (i1 < len(lines1) and i2 < len(lines2)):
    line1 = lines1[i1]
    line2 = lines2[i2]
    if line1 < line2:    
        i1 += 1
    elif line1 > line2:
        i2 += 1
    else:
        matchCount += 1
        i2 += 1

print('matchCount')    
print(matchCount)
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorting won't quite help, as start of match may be not at the start of the line. I should have posted examples originally, but I added them now

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to use UNIX/GNU/Linux commands you could do this:

```bash
# fill example files
for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done > file1.txt
for i in {1..200000}; do echo $RANDOM; done > file2.txt

# get every line of file2.txt which is also in file1.txt
# for static string matching:
grep -F -x -f file1.txt file2.txt

# for regex matching use (regular expressions in file1.txt):
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

`grep` is optimized for such operations so the above call takes less than a second (have a look at [this](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html)).

Comment: It works wonders for non-regexp search. I tried to write regexps in a file and grep them from file2, but, apparently, 4gb of RAM is not enough, as I get:
grep.exe: Memory exhausted

Comment: I've updated my question to be able to have regex in file1.
How big are the files you are using? And how long are the lines within the files?